# What is the R way to print out all values of a vector using cat?

Tags: r, function, apply

For formatting purposes, I want to print out the values of an array using cat().

I can do this easily using a for loop... but I want to do it the "right" way.

```
randNums <- rnorm(5)
for(i in randNums){
  cat("n")
  cat(",")
  cat(i)
  cat("\n")
}
```

Output:

```
n,-0.06339912
n,1.276653
n,0.1581441
n,-1.347136
n,1.777113
```

By the "right way", I mean using one of the apply functions as opposed to a for loop.

Comment: Sorry, by the "right" way, I mean using one of the apply functions as opposed to using a for loop.

Comment: `apply` isnt always the "right" way to avoid using `for` - sometimes a vectorised solution presents itself, as seen in the answers so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your exact output form, with "n," and the value:

```
> cat(paste("n", randNums,sep=",", collapse="\n"), '\n')
n,-0.135970405811417
n,2.19536614784033
n,0.567067477368411
n,1.97238205385431
n,-0.34726999999616
```

using `apply`-family functions leads to this sort of mess:

```
> invisible(lapply(randNums,function(x){cat("n,",x,"\n",sep="")}))
n,1.56346
n,1.360061
n,2.048337
n,0.234013
n,0.1050811
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
cat(paste(seq_along(randNums), randNums,sep=",", collapse="\n"), '\n')
```

If you need 'n'

```
cat(paste('n', randNums,sep=",", collapse="\n"), '\n')
```